# ggparagraph is not displayed

Tags: r, ggpubr

I have problem with the function **ggparagraph()** from **ggpubr** package. Its content is not drawing. If I use the function:

```
example(ggparagraph)
```

The plot is drawing without any problem, but the "ggparagraph area" (below plot) is empty. The same problem is if I use custom scripts, where the ggparagraph is applied.

[image: function output]
R does not print any error message. Where can be the problem?

My session info is:

sessionInfo()

> R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 15063)
>   Matrix products: default
>   locale:
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxMBL.png) LC_COLLATE=Slovak_Slovakia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Slovak_Slovakia.1250
>   [3] LC_MONETARY=Slovak_Slovakia.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=Slovak_Slovakia.1250
>   attached base packages:
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxMBL.png) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>   other attached packages:
>    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxMBL.png) ggpubr_0.1.4    magrittr_1.5    gridExtra_2.2.1 dplyr_0.7.2
>    [5] purrr_0.2.3     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.6.3     tibble_1.3.3
>    [9] ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.1.1
>   loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxMBL.png) Rcpp_0.12.12     cellranger_1.1.0 compiler_3.4.1   plyr_1.8.4
>    [5] bindr_0.1        forcats_0.2.0    tools_3.4.1      jsonlite_1.5
>    [9] lubridate_1.6.0  nlme_3.1-131     gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35 
>   [13] pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.1.2      psych_1.7.5      parallel_3.4.1
>   [17] haven_1.1.0      bindrcpp_0.2     xml2_1.1.1       stringr_1.2.0
>   [21] httr_1.2.1       hms_0.3          cowplot_0.8.0    grid_3.4.1
>   [25] glue_1.1.1       R6_2.2.2         readxl_1.0.0     foreign_0.8-69
>   [29] reshape2_1.4.2   modelr_0.1.1     scales_0.4.1     rvest_0.3.2
>   [33] assertthat_0.2.0 mnormt_1.5-5     colorspace_1.3-2 labeling_0.3
>   [37] stringi_1.1.5    lazyeval_0.2.0   munsell_0.4.3    broom_0.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I don't find where is the problem, but if I install this package from github (instead of CRAN), all paragraphs are rendered correctly.